# I need to figure out how to save the user input as the new variables, not sure what to do from here

Tags: python, class, input

#I need to figure out how to save the user input as the new variables, not sure what to do from here.

```
    class Person:
    
        def __init__(self):
#I'm supposed to have the object set to these generic names at first and then after the prompt function they need to be updated.
            self.name = 'anonymous' 
            self.b_year = 'unknown'
    
        def prompt(self):
            print('Please enter the following:')
            self.name = input('Name: ')
            self.b_year = input('Year: ')
            b = Book()
            b.prompt()
    
    
        def display(self):
            print(f'Author:\n{self.name} (b. {self.b_year})\n')
    
    class Book:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.title = 'untitled'
            self.publisher = 'unpublished'
    
        def prompt(self):
            self.title = input('Title: ')
            self.publisher = input('Publisher: ')
    
        def display(self):
            print(f'\n{self.title}\nPublisher:\n{self.publisher}')
            p = Person()
            `enter code here`p.display()
    
    def main():
        p = Person()
        b = Book()
        
        b.display()
        p.prompt() 
        b.display() #right here I need it to display the new information
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: The Person prompt should not be doing the Book prompt, especially since you immediately throw away the object, and the Book displayer should not be displaying a person.  Book and Person should not know anything about each other.  Let `main` do the prompting and decide what to display.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do here. First of all you need to initialize your variables in your `Person` class. Second of all I don't understand what the point of creating objects in a class and then doing the same outside of the class. I suggest taking the following code and modifying it to your likings. Additionally I reorganized the way you call your methods. First you prompt the user with all the necessary questions, then display them all together.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.b_year = None

    def prompt(self):
        print('Please enter the following:')
        self.name = input('Name: ')
        self.b_year = input('Year: ')


    def display(self):
        print(f'Author:\n{self.name} (b. {self.b_year})\n')


class Book:

    def __init__(self):
        self.title = 'untitled'
        self.publisher = 'unpublished'

    def prompt(self):
        self.title = input('Title: ')
        self.publisher = input('Publisher: ')

    def display(self):
        print(f'\n{self.title}\nPublisher:\n{self.publisher}')




def main():
    p = Person()
    b = Book()

    b.display()
    p.display()
    p.prompt() 
    b.prompt()
    b.display()
    p.display()#right here I need it to display the new information

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output

```
untitled
Publisher:
unpublished
Author:
None (b. None)

Please enter the following:
Name: a
Year: b
Title: c
Publisher: d

c
Publisher:
d
Author:
a (b. b)
```

I'm not designer so you don't have to go with my idea, but IMO, don't add `\n` like this `'\n{self.title}\nPublisher:\n{self.publisher}'`. It looks a bit weird in the output.

Comment: This is for a school assignment, it needs to print out a first set of data with all the unknown variables, then give the user a chance to input new variables, and print the new information out. All the \n are just the way they wanted it to be formatted.

Answer (score -1):

You create one `Book` in the main function, and then another `Book` inside the `Person.prompt` method. They aren't the same `Book` - you have two!

You need to decide if a book belongs within a person, or whether they are two top level objects that may have a relationship. From a "real world" perspective, I don't think a person should automatically have a book associated with them. Perhaps you could create a `Book` and then pass to the `Person` constructor...